# How to declare a 2d array to hold objects from multiple classes

Tags: arrays, object, 2d, processing

I have declared an array which stores objects of type Square as follows:

```
Square[][] square_array = new Square[15][15];
```

I also have a class called Ball.

Is it possible to store Ball objects in the square_array? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Cheers

Comment: You can create another array of Ball objects side by side your square_array or depending on how Square and Ball relate to each other, you could for example use composition to nest a Ball instance inside the Square class so you would essentially group the two functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps make an object class and have square and ball  to extends it, than you can make an objects array that can contain both... Inheritance seams to be old fashion though...

```
Sq sq = new Sq();
Ba ba = new Ba();
Ob[] sqAndBa = new Ob[2];

void setup() {
  sqAndBa[0] = sq; 
  sqAndBa[1] = ba;
  println(sqAndBa);
}


class Ob {
}

class Sq extends Ob {
  String toString() {
    return("I'm a square");
  }
}

class Ba extends Ob {
  String toString() {
    return("I'm a ball");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [v.k.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16860937/2441384) answer about extending a general object class (this makes iteratively displaying from your array easier), you may also consider using an ArrayList which accepts any number of different types of objects:

```
Sq sq = new Sq();
Ba ba = new Ba();
ArrayList sqAndBa = new ArrayList();

void setup() {
sqAndBa.add(sq);
sqAndBa.add(ba);

void draw() {
// now iterate through your ArrayList and display your objects:
for (int i = 0; sqAndBa.size(); i++) {
    Ob ob = (Ob) sqAndBa.get(i);
    ob.display();

class Ob {
    // construction and display methods common to both
}

class Sq extends Ob {
    // construction or display methods particular to squares
    return sq;
}

class Ba extends Ob {
    // construction and display methods particular to circles
    return ba;
}
```

Comment: Ideed that's true. In this case you don't even need to create a parent class. But you need to cast them out.